# Is there any problems when using more than one v-app in nuxt layouts

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Vuetify [official documentations](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application) has the following statement about v-app:
**v-app should only be used within your application ONCE**.
I think this recommendation is true for simple SPAs.

Using nuxt.js I have different layouts for my app and I'd like to use more than one v-app in my layouts - one v-app per layout.

At first glance everything works fine, but I'm new to frontend developing and I would like to know are there any gotchas or hidden problems when ignoring Vuetify recommendation about single v-app per application?

I'm using vuetify 2.0.19, nuxt 2.9.2 and vue 2.6.10.
Application is the simple blog engine which has two layouts - common blog posts and admin panel.

Answer (score 2):

I asked about this on Vuetify/Nuxt Discord and core team member answered that since only one layout is rendered at a time, it's fine to have many layouts each with `<v-app/>` at the root

Answer (score 0):

I am also confused.

The docs says

> v-app can exist anywhere inside the body of your app, however, there should only be one and it must be the parent of ALL Vuetify components.

Maybe, we can use v-app in each template/component, but when the application is running there can only be one v-app.

For example
MainContainer.vue

```
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

FirstPage.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app> ... </v-app>
</template>
```

SecondPage.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app> ... </v-app>
</template>
```

FirstPage and SeconPage are registered on the vue-router as follows

```
{
  "path": "/",
  "redirect": "first-page",
  "component": MainContainer,
  "children": [
    {
      "path": "first",
      "name": "first-page",
      "component": FirstPage,
    },
    {
      "path": "second",
      "name": "second-page",
      "component": SecondPage,
    }
  ]
}
```

So, when the application runs, there is only one v-app

Please correct me if I'm wrong